# running executable from python with keyboard input

Tags: python

I am calling a command line executable from python:

```
import subprocess
import os

def genParFiles(program):
    Path = "C:/00Working/99CygwinBin/"

    def exe_call(program):
        fullPath = Path + program
        subprocess.call(fullPath)

    exe_call(program)


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

This works fine. The exe runs in the interpreter window.

Now, the program that I'm calling is waiting for me to press enter to start calculating, which I can do in the interpreter window with no problem.

My question is, how can I automate the 'enter' so I don't have to press it manually?

Comment: You can try this: http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect

Comment: check out the docs for [subprocess.call](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) - you can provide an argument for `stdin` and presumably pass input through that?

Comment: @kaveman Ok... So what would I pass? I tried subprocess.call(fullPath, stdin=" ") but that did not work.

Comment: did you read the docs, at that link?

*`stdin`...Valid values are `PIPE`, an existing file descriptor (a positive integer), an existing file object, and `None`*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly straightforward with `Popen`:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(fullPath, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
stdO, stdE = p.communicate("foo\n")
```

::edit:: Fixed communicate call as pointed out in comments.

Comment: If you're using Python 3, then you will want to remove shell=True and add universal_newlines=True

Comment: @dg99 Thanks for the help. I am using Python 3. The first line works and is calling the program. But I am getting an error with the 2nd line. "If self._communication_started and input: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_communication_started'"  Any guidance you can give would be appreciated!

Comment: @dg99 also, that second line should be subprocess.Popen.communicate right?

Comment: @dg99 Nevermind, I got it. I made the 2nd line say: "stdO = p.communicate("foo\n") and that worked. Thanks for the tip.